# How to get current time in Android?

Tags: java, android, time

I need to get the time when the user is touching a button. like, when the user is touching button1, I need it to save the exact hour, minute and date of touching this button. how can I do it?

Answer (score 6):

You can try the following code:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

You can use this function to escape creation of date object.

You can persist it as long and you always can create Date object of it.